# How to find all references to a specific file in source control within Team Foundation Server

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am trying to find the simplest best way to find all the programs in our source control that use a particular .vb file. Is there an easy way to do this or do I just need to go through each program and search for my particular file?

Comment: programs dont use any .vb file. they use DLL reference.

Comment: The .vb file I'm referring to is within the project of many of the programs (projects) I need to search. Basically instead of opening each program in tfs individually I wanted to be able to do a search as if I opened each project and looked at the files that make up the project.

Comment: You would need to look at all of the .vbproj files to see if they referenced a file with the same name. You then might want to find out if it's "the same file".

Comment: Do you know how I can do this in in visual studio 2012 source control explorer? I have around 100 programs to sift threw.

Answer (score 1):

Ok thanks to some of my colleagues here is how to do it. To find any files within your project you can search the .vbproj file. If you download grepWin you can search a directory for a specified file based on its ext. (.vbproj), then you can put in the file you are looking for and search. It will return a listing of all the programs/.vbproj files that contain the text you searched for.